# How to update function code in an R package?

Tags: r, rstudio, devtools, roxygen2, rtools

I have created and downloaded an R package using roxygen2 development tools. When I update the source code R files, the documentation updates fine, but the function code itself does not. How do I get the function code to update when I reinstall the package with install.packages("package-name")?

I have tried inserting error messages at the beginning of every function using stop("..."). When I reinstall the code, the functions do not output an error message as they should but work as they did before I updated the code.

Each time I update the code, I use the following commands:

```
devtools::document()
devtools::install()

install.packages("package-name", repos=NULL, type="source")
library(package-name)
```

Just for further information, when I try to install the package this way:

```
install.packages("package-name")
```

I get the following error message:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘package-name’ is not available (for R version 3.6.0)
```

I got this same error message when my R version was 3.6.0, and even now after updating to 3.6.1

I have not uploaded the package to any repositories, so I figured this makes sense, and instead install it locally from my package files with repos=NULL.

```
#' Roxygen comments - this part updates
#'
#' etc.
functionName <- function(...) {
 stop("...") 
 ...
 # This function should crash with an error message every time it is called, 
 # but instead the function body is never updated.
}
```

Upon reinstalling the package, I expect the output of my functions to be an error message, but instead, they output the same result as they did before I updated the package.

Documentation updates, function bodies do not.

Comment: Apparently you use RStudio, what to you get when clicking "Install and restart" in the Build Panel?

Comment: Turns out the issue had nothing to do with the R version error, but a suppressed warning that was preventing the source code from updating. I posted the solution that worked for me below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out I found an answer to my own question...

The problem was with a warning message I was getting:

```
Warning message: 
In body(fun) : argument is not a function
```

Despite not ever using `body()`, this function was getting called internally somewhere, and the warning prevented the code from being updated (but the documentation still updates, for some reason).

Clearing my global environment with `rm(list=ls())` cleared my error.